# BsDatePicker hiding behind modal

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datetimepicker

```
<!-- The Server Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="serverModal">
    <div
        class="modal-dialog"
        style="max-width: 80%;overflow-y: initial !important;"
    >
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    User # {{ globals.currentUser }}
                </h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div
                class="modal-body"
                style="max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    overflow-y: auto;"
            >
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6" style="width:150px;">
                                        ObsoleteServerActionDate
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-6">
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            placeholder="DOJ"
                                            class="form-control"
                                            bsDatepicker
                                            [bsConfig]="{
                                                dateInputFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                                                containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue' 
                                            }"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    data-dismiss="modal"
                    (click)="SaveServer()"
                >
                    Save
                </button>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-danger"
                    data-dismiss="modal"
                    (click)="CancelServer()"
                >
                    Cancel
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the table inside the modal there is a `bsDatePicker`. When I open the modal the date-picker simply hides behind the modal.

I have tried the `z-index` solution by giving a class to the `bsDatePicker` input element and setting its `z-index: 3000 !important` but it still shows behind the modal. Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to set `z-index` to the container element. You should be doing this instead:

```
.theme-dark-blue {
   z-index: 3000 !important;
}
```

---

As this is having a config property, you can utilize that:

```
[bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY', containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue show-at-top' }"

.show-at-top{
   z-index: 3000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . Unfortunately it still doesn't work .

Comment: What actually happens if you apply this style? Can you post that too? Does the targeted element have this css class applied?

Comment: The css class 'theme-dark-blue' is not being applied . Is there any css file I should include ?

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#config-object check this one

Answer (score 0):

In the parent chain of the input element you need to give css `position:relative` to first `td`

Below input element in your code needs to have a parent with `position:relative`

```
<input type="text"
       placeholder="DOJ"
       class="form-control"
       bsDatepicker 
       [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY', containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue' }"
>
```

I once fixed this issue by doing it in the first `td` element in the parent chain